# Python: import cv2 not working after installing opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script using cv2. I never had problems in the past.
Now when installing opencv-python or opencv-contrib-python, cv2 module is not found.

Any ideas as to why this is? TIA

I read https://breakthrough.github.io/Installing-OpenCV/ but I've been running it on Python 3.10 and 3.11 with no problem. Is it because I am now trying on 3.12?

I also read the previous answers, but again that doesn't explain why I was running it on 3.10 and 3.11.

````
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in c:\users\blixxky\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (4.8.1.78)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\blixxky\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.26.1)


py -c "import cv2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Blixxky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Blixxky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Blixxky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.```
````

Comment: Show us the output of this command `py --version`

Comment: C:\>py --version
Python 3.12.0

It's a fresh install, it's the only python env i've installed. No conda, no other py version.

Comment: It looks like you might have two separate installations of python 3.12.  Show us this output `py -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: C:\>py -c "import sys; print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\Blixxky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Blixxky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Blixxky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\Blixxky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\Blixxky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. There's a missing DLL.  Typically those are installed by some other way, not from using `pip`.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix this? Did the install just fumble? I tried Python's installation repair after you said that, but it made no difference. Thanks for your assistance, you rock.

Comment: The cv2 homepage https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ addresses this exact error.

Comment: Thank you. I'll RTFM. Appreciate the help.